# Multiple vanity URLs for different php files?

Tags: php, .htaccess, web

I am trying to build a site which has the following pages which needs vanity urls,

- account.php
- questions.php
- profile.php

I need to display

www.mysite.com/account?req=settings 
www.mysite.com/account?req=questions 
www.mysite.com/account?req=answers

as following

www.mysite.com/account/settings 
www.mysite.com/account/questions 
www.mysite.com/account/answers

And for the other files I need the following,

etc:- 
www.mysite.com/questions?id=0484684

As

www.mysite.com/questions/0484684

And

www.mysite.com/profile?id=123456

as

www.mysite.com/profile/123456

Would anyone help me because I really need to make this possible.

I would like to remove the .php extention from the url too.

I like to say that I have no experience in htaccess files.

Thanks for the help, it worked !!!

Comment: Does your PHP site run inside of Apache?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `.htaccess` file, add these rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^account/([^/\.]+)/?$ account.php?req=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^questions/([^/\.]+)/?$ questions.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/\.]+)/?$ profile.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

You should be able to add new rules based on how these work if you need them in the future.

Comment: this doesn't remove the php extention of all the files

Comment: After copying this to the htaccess file there was no styles in my pages

Comment: The visible URL would be `www.mysite.com/account/settings` - so no PHP extension as far as the visitor is concerned. Your stylesheet probably has a relative path, you can probably fix it be adding a slash at the start, i.e. `"/style.css"`

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a `.htaccess` file combined with PHP for complex manipulations like that, I wrote an article on re-writing URLs after asking a similar question on SO:

http://tomsbigbox.com/elegant-url-rewriting/